# Options for auto setting a date input field

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

When presenting a user with a date input form

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="date" value="{{ old('date') }}">
```

Most of the time although not always the user needs to enter todays date.

What are my options for setting the default value to todays date.

Im using Blade, PHP, Bootstrap, Laravel, CSS, HTML

If any of them resources have something to handle this.

Thanks in advance for any feedback it's appreciated.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: How is that relevant, I can't even se the date by using
    value="02/12/2015"

Comment: What have you tried? That is a link to PHP documentation, which shows you how to output a date, such as todays date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP to echo the date:

```
<?php $today = date("m/d/Y"); ?>
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="date" value="<?php echo $today; ?>">
```

This will echo a date in the format of Month/Date/Year, e.g. `12/31/2000`

The documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) explains in more detail on how to format the date

Answer (score 0):

The function `old()` takes a second parameter, the default.  Using the link provided by user Chris, it looks like you want the format `d/m/Y`.  With that in mind, the following should do the trick.

```
{{ old('date', date('d/m/Y')) }}
```